# After 8.1 lost grub. Can i just uninstall Linux?

Tags: grub2, uninstall

I dual booted Ubuntu alongside my windows 8. After installing windows 8.1 I lost grub and it boots straight into 8.1 and i have a watermark that says "secureboot isn't configured correctly". But I've been wanting to uninstall Linux for a while to reclaim memory for my steam games on windows, the only thing that keeps holding me back is the thought of dealing with grub. But since windows 8.1 knocked it out, what would happen if I just deleted my Linux partitions and reallocated that memory? And what's the watermark all about?

Comment: You should make a separate question for the watermark problem on [superuser](http://superuser.com/). Windows issues are off-topic here and you shouldn't combine questions anyway.

Comment: I just wasnt sure if secure boot had anything to do with grub because It was an error in the boot configurations and im kind of a noob when it comes to that kind of stuff. Im sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just trash your Linux partitions, **lose all the data on them in the process**, and resize a Windows partition to reclaim the free space.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I trashed my linux partitions, and everything was fine. it wouldnt let me merge the unallocated memory with my c drive because they werent continguous on the partition table so I formated the unallocated memory as a windows partition to store data so I still have that storage that i can access. Ive already put 3 games on. And I forgot I had to disable secureboot to install linux but booting into bios, going to boot options and enabling secure boot ridded me of the watermark and had no effect on my system. You can disable it anytime you wanna boot into linux or something. Hope this helps anyone who was having the same issues as me!